# javascript prevent middle mouse button from opening link in new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

On some websites, you can right-click on a link and chose "open in a new tab" and it works fine, but not if one uses the middle mouse button to do so.
I encountered this a few times, it's it not too annoying but I'm still curious what causes this behaviour. (About the HOW)
Here is a site that behaves this way browsing with Chrome 46:
http://ebookfriendly.com/free-public-domain-books-sources/
the html link tags looks normal:

```html
<a title="Feedbooks" href="http://www.feedbooks.com/">⇢ Feedbooks</a>
```

The cause must be something in the javascript. Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like this link has an event listener that uses `preventDefault()` and opens the page by other means.

Edit: hard to say why *exactly* they do this but when I look at the whole handler it seems that the link is being passed to google analytics:

```
function(e) {
    var n = this.getAttribute("href"),
        i = "string" == typeof this.getAttribute("target") ? this.getAttribute("target") : "";
    ga("send", "event", "outbound", "click", n, {
        hitCallback: t(n, i)
    }, {
        nonInteraction: 1
    }), e.preventDefault()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. As a "frontend_dev" can you tell me any reason for this practice?

Comment: See my revised answer above. So it seems due to Google Analytics.

Comment: The answer here will help you out, just make sure that you access the keycode of the middle button of the mouse and do a statement to check if it is that button (I think its 2) else you will prevent all click events from working on the link/links at all

Answer (score 9):

One way to do this is using the `auxclick` event. ([auxclick on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/auxclick_event))

The following code will prevent the middle click behaviour on the entire page.

```
window.addEventListener("auxclick", (event) => {
  if (event.button === 1) event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can ask which button caused the event and prevent the default behavior.

```
document.querySelector("a").addEventListener("click", function(e) { 
   if (e.which === 2) {
      e.preventDefault();
   } 
}, false);
```

Comment: Good Answer, i just made a comment about checking the correct keycode on the accepted answer. +1

Comment: So, if the expected behaviour is prevented by preventDefault() the link will still be opened because there is some function listening to the mouseup event I guess?

Comment: The link will not to be opened in case you use the middle mouse, in other cases the browser will behave as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).mousedown(function(e){
        if(e.which == 2 ){
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("middle click");   
            return false;
        }
    });
```

works only if you keep the alert()